# rounding to desired digits in MATLAB and C

Tags: c, matlab, rounding

I've read the questions regarding the implementation of rounding in C, inspired by MATLAB round function and I followed their advice but the result is not at all what it should be. Here's part of my code regarding this issue:

```
    movmean_h[i]=(double)sum/(f-b);
    mexPrintf("\t movmean_h[%d]=%e",i,movmean_h[i]);
    movmean_h[i]=(double)round(movmean_h[i]*n)/n;
    mexPrintf("\t movmean_h[%d]=%e",i,movmean_h[i]);
```

And part of the result is like this(this code is run in a loop):

```
 movmean_h[10261]=2.283693e-13   movmean_h[10261]=1.668138e-06
 movmean_h[10261]=2.283693e-13   movmean_h[10261]=1.668138e-06
 movmean_h[10262]=2.288172e-13   movmean_h[10262]=1.483963e-06
 movmean_h[10263]=2.292687e-13   movmean_h[10263]=-8.838173e-07
 movmean_h[10264]=2.297219e-13   movmean_h[10264]=0.000000e+00
 movmean_h[10265]=2.292835e-13   movmean_h[10265]=2.138378e-06
 movmean_h[10266]=2.288319e-13   movmean_h[10266]=1.409754e-06
 movmean_h[10267]=2.283839e-13   movmean_h[10267]=0.000000e+00
 movmean_h[10268]=2.279412e-13   movmean_h[10268]=-2.147484e-06
 movmean_h[10269]=2.275056e-13   movmean_h[10269]=-2.147484e-06
 movmean_h[10270]=2.270787e-13   movmean_h[10270]=-2.147484e-06
 movmean_h[10262]=2.288172e-13   movmean_h[10262]=1.483963e-06
 movmean_h[10263]=2.292687e-13   movmean_h[10263]=-8.838173e-07
 movmean_h[10264]=2.297219e-13   movmean_h[10264]=0.000000e+00
 movmean_h[10265]=2.292835e-13   movmean_h[10265]=2.138378e-06
 movmean_h[10266]=2.288319e-13   movmean_h[10266]=1.409754e-06
 movmean_h[10267]=2.283839e-13   movmean_h[10267]=0.000000e+00
 movmean_h[10268]=2.279412e-13   movmean_h[10268]=-2.147484e-06
 movmean_h[10269]=2.275056e-13   movmean_h[10269]=-2.147484e-06
 movmean_h[10270]=2.270787e-13   movmean_h[10270]=-2.147484e-06
```

The answers do not match at all, not in order and not in the decimals, which in theory they would match.

And 'n' is defined as:

```
long int n=pow(10,15);
```

So my question is why my code is wrong, or is there something I'm missing?
By the way I am writing my C code for a MATLAB mex-file.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Olaf is correct: We need a [mcve] and we need the expected result.

Comment: Does code have `#include <math.h>` before using `round()` to properly prototype `round()` - or is `round()` your own code?  The `(double)` cast in `(double)round(movmean_h[i]*n)/n;` is suspicious - it should not be needed.

Comment: Yes @chux. Thanks. That was the problem. I added math.h and it works fine now. Also the double is not necessary and it doesn't change the result.

Comment: @AboozarRoosta Normally casting should be avoided. A lot of casting like this is normally indicating that something is wrong (like that you were missing some headers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code lacked a declaration of declaration of `double round()`.  Older compilers allow this, yet interpret the result then an `int`.  Code output is then quite bizarre.  The hint, for me, was that many nearby `double` inputs had the same result.

```
// add
#include <math.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

10^15 doesn't fit into a `long int` on a Windows machine. Use a `double`.

```
double n = pow(10, 15);
movmean_h[i]=(double)sum/(f-b);
mexPrintf("\t movmean_h[%d]=%e",i,movmean_h[i]);
movmean_h[i]=round(movmean_h[i]*n)/n;
mexPrintf("\t movmean_h[%d]=%e",i,movmean_h[i]);
```

Comment: Tried it now. It doesn't work. Still the same results.